Importing X509 Certificate from Base64 String Fails in Deployment but Works in Local
In my application I need to read a base64 string from database and create a X509 Certificate.
That string was created by another piece of code by reading a PFX file, and converting it to byte Array and then into a Base64 String - like this.
Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePfxPath));

Here is the code I have written to retrieve it back.
string certificatePassword = "my_password";   
string cert64String = ""; // Read the base64 string from DB.

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();
certificate.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(cert64String), certificatePassword,
     X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable |
     X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |
     X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);     

The code works fine in my local machine, but when I deploy it to Azure app service, the code throws the following error:
The system cannot find the file specified.
stack track 
at system.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils.LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle pCertCtx)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags, Boolean passwordProvided)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData)

I thought the X509KeyStorageFlags parameters must be responsible for this issue, so I tried a second approach like this.
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cert64String);
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(bytes);

But this is also throwing the same error. I am not able to understand why it says about A File Path whereas I am not dealing with any file operation here!
what am I doing wrong here? How can I fix this in the deployment environment ?

Finally I solved the problem after a lot of analysis. Posting here so that it can help somebody in future.
Apparently certificate.Import tries to write into the host machine's certificate store, which was the reason for the error.
I changed the approach to create the certificate without using the Import function. The following code works for me.
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(cert64String), 
        certificatePassword,
        X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | 
        X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | 
        X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

